# Geometric interpretation of $\{Q, P\}_{q, p}$ in a Hamiltonian coordinate transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamilton-equations

**Context.** I am reading a physics book in which it shown that, in the Hamiltonian setting, a bijective coordinate transformation

$$
q \rightarrow Q \text{ s.t. }Q = Q(q,p)\\
p \rightarrow P \text{ s.t. }P = P(q, p)
$$

preserves the Hamilton equations

$$
\frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial P} \\
\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{\partial \tilde{H}}{\partial Q}
$$

where $\tilde{H} = H(Q^{-1}(Q,P), P^{-1}(Q,P))$, if and only if the Poisson bracket of $P$ and $Q$ satisfies

$$
\{Q, P\}_{q, p} = \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q} \frac{\partial P}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial p} \frac{\partial P}{\partial q}\right )\ne 0
$$

It is apparently also usually desired that $\{Q, P\}_{q, p} = 1$.

**Question:** Is there a **geometric interpretation** (or some other sort of intuitive explanation) as to what the condition $\{Q, P\}_{q, p} = 0$ means, and why it destroys the Hamiltonian equations?